# The using rules of %eax, %edx, %ecx in the same function frame

Tags: assembly, x86, calling-convention, att, i386

Env: i386 32-bit
Assembly: AT&T
OS: Linux

I just want to ask that is there any rule on the sequence of using `%eax, %edx, %ecx` register when you use them with in the same function frame.

As my observation, they often showed up on my environment with the sequence of `%ecx`, `%edx` and then `%eax` to store the local variables or other temporary variables.

Thanks to you all.

Comment: There is no such rule.  However, keep in mind that some registers are *callee-saved* and must be restored to their original values on exit from the function.  On i386 Linux, these are `rbx`, `rsi`, `rdi`, `rsp`, and `rbp`; the floating point stack must be empty, too (except if you return a floating point number that is).

Comment: got it, thank you.

Comment: Refer to the i386 SysV ABI for further reading.  That documents specifies all rules you need to obey when writing i386 assembly functions for Linux.

Comment: @fuz You mean `ebx`, `esi`, `edi`, `esp` and `rbp`? I don't think 64-bit registers are available on the 80386.

Comment: @fcdt Yes, indeed.  Brainfart...

Comment: @fcdt You mean `ebp`? I don't think 64-bit registers are available on the 80386. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, is has to do with the [i386 System V ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/intel386-psABI-1.1.pdf) (more links in the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)):

`eax`, `ecx` and `edx` are scratch registers, they don't have to be preserved across function calls. All other 32-bit general-purpose registers must be saved on the stack, which costs additional instructions.

Therefore it is best to initially use `eax`, `ecx` and `edx` first in the same function and only afterwards `ebx`, `esi`, `edi`, `esp` and `ebp`.

*(I have omitted the percent signs here for the sake of legibility)*

Comment: Re: omitting the `%` signs: the register names don't contain `%`.  AT&T syntax uses `%` decorations on reg names to avoid ambiguity between register names and symbol names, but that doesn't mean the decoration is part of the register name proper.  e.g. in GNU C inline asm, the clobber list can just use `"eax"` (or GCC accepts `"%eax"` there as well.)

Comment: Thanks for the note. They were included in the ABI document so I assumed that (normally I only work with intel syntax).

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of [What registers must be preserved by an x86 function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9603003), but I guess pointing out explicitly that using call-clobbered registers saves work doing save/restore is the real crux of the answer, so +1.  (Fun fact: all mainstream 32-bit x86 function-calling conventions agree on EAX, ECX, and EDX being call-clobbered, with the rest being call-preserved.)